# Can you find the Error in my SQL syntax?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

I try to build my Visual Studio project that get SQL data.

Error is: 1064 Error retrieving database information. Error in SQL syntax.

I don't know where the error is.

```
 sQuery = string.Format("select distinct stringid from {0} where TIMESTAMPDIFF( day, insertts, now() ) < 30 " +
          "and status = '{2}' and stringid not in (select distinct stringid from {1} where TIMESTAMPDIFF( day, insertts, now() ) < 30)",
```

Anything will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: can you print sQuery already formatted with values? might be some problem with the parameter data that you provide

Comment: @Martin My bad. Did not see the details in code. There's code missing. So I'm not THAT multitasking.

Comment: Can you please step into sQuery and print out the output of sQuery for us on here please.

Comment: @Martin et al, error 1064 is a common MySQL one meaning "your syntax is hosed".

Comment: MySQL RDBMS running remotely on another computer. I get data for another application just no data for the one that has this code. Sorry I am fairly new to this.

Comment: Show us the whole code, so we can help. Remember: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/stack-overflow-none-of-us-is-as-dumb-as-all-of-us.html

Answer (score 3):

That string formatting operation looks fine to me (albeit with limited information) but there are a couple of possibilities.

1. Check that the resulting string is of a valid format. By that, I mean print out `sQuery` before executing it. Since MySQL error 1064 is a fairly generic "bad syntax" error, it may be that the parameters given to `String.Format` are forming a bad query (such as `{2}` containing a `'` character).
2. Make sure the target DBMS is running MySQL 5 or greater. `TIMESTAMPDIFF` was not available before then.
3. Try to run that exact same query (using what you print in (1) above) in the actual target DBMS rather than through your code. Error 1064 usually gives you a `near 'blah blah blah'` addendum to the error message which helps work out exactly *where* in the statement the problem lies.